# How we can create compound index programmatically in gcp firestore database in Nodejs?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

Firestore need compound index for a range and equal comparison together. Lets say user collection, query:

```
this.fireStoreDB.collection('users').where('user', 'in', [111, 222, 333]).where('timestamp' > '2019-01-01').
```

It will give link if compound index is not there to manually create that compound index via link.
Is there a programtic way to create same dynamically in Node or any other language?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible in Firestore by design. The reason for that is because the whole idea behind indexes is that it should be part of your development flow to identify if you need any composite indexes for more complex queries.

Not to mention that if you automate it, it's very likely that you reach the limit of 200 composite indexes by database very fast.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Google APIs to make a post request with indexes in the request body.

For example:

```
POST https://firestore.googleapis.com/v1beta1/{parent=projects/*/databases/*}/indexes
```

Documentation: https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/reference/rest/v1beta1/projects.databases.indexes/create